# How to manage Elastic mapping changes with ILM rollovers?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, rollover

We have some Elastic rollover indices managed by ILM. Mappings are defined in templates.

When we try to add mappings fields concepts collide:

The obvious way is (1) update the template and (2) provoke a rollover so the new index has the new mapping. BUT rolling over an ILM managed index breaks things. `_ilm/explain` will tell you `index [blah] is not the write index for alias [blah-000004]`.

So... what do people do?

Directly updating the write index mapping might work, but it feels like there should be a better option?

This is Elastic 6.8.

Comment: Can you show how you've set this all up (commands and rollover, etc)?